# Why is the Octave conv() giving result different from manual convolution of two signals?

Tags: signal-processing, octave, convolution

I am trying to write my own code in Octave for convolution of two discreet signals. But when I compared the output with the in-built `conv()` function, it is coming different. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
clc; clear; close all;
[h, fs] = audioread('sound_h.wav');
h = h(1:10000,1);
[x, fs] = audioread('sound_x.wav');
x = x(1:50000,1);
subplot(4, 1, 1)
plot(x);
title("x[n]");
subplot(4, 1, 2)
plot(h);
title("h[n]");
flip_h = fliplr(h);
len_h = length(h);
len_x = length(x);
padded_x = [zeros(len_h-1,1);x;zeros(len_h-1,1)];
y = zeros(len_x+len_h-1,1);
for i = 1:length(y)
  y(i) = sum(padded_x(i:i+len_h-1).*flip_h);
endfor
subplot(4, 1, 3)
plot(y);
title("y[n]");
subplot(4, 1, 4)
plot(conv(h, x));
title("y[n] using conv()");
```

Here are the plots:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you debug you code with signals, where the output is known. For example a gaussian and a dirac

Comment: And btw, no one can run your code because the input files are missing

Comment: @Andy you can use any file. its stills give different output. Is my code correct though

Comment: You should always try to generate a MCVE which would be very easy in your case. Sinve you are asking others to spent their valuable time your intrest should be to make it as easy as possible for others to help you.

Comment: what is a mcve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
flip_h = fliplr(h);
```

does nothing, because

```
h = h(1:10000,1);
```

is a column vector. You need to use `flipud` in this case.